# Видео HTML 5 почему то не начинается автовоспроизведение

Tags: html, css, html5, видео

Видео не начинает воспроизводится, "застряёт" на первом кадре.
Если в браузере нажимаю кнопку показать управление, и нажимаю плей, воспроизведение начинается.
Такое же поведение если пишу control в атрибутах тега.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay="true" loop="true">
        <source src="/video/video-640_adpp.mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: должен помочь атрибут muted, но видео будет без звука...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvMzBxR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автовоспроизведение видео на странице может быть установлено только без звука.

Чтобы autoplay="true" работал, нужно добавить еще и **muted="true/muted"**

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй autoplay="autoplay"

Comment: autoplay="autoplay", было изначально поменял на true в попытках пофиксить

Comment: <source src="/video/video-640_adpp.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: mime type тоже не помогает(